# How to perform arithmetic operations in bash script on fractions?

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm trying to create simple bash script which stores in x variable number of lines of abc.csv file and then stores in a, b and c variables results of some arithmetic operations. When I run the script I get errors:

> let: not found

and

> arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "0.2*"

The script:

```
let x=$(wc -l abc.csv | awk '{print $1}')
let a_size= $((0.2*$x))
let b_size=$((2*0.2*$x))
let c_size=$((2*0.2*$x+1))
```

How to perform arithmetic operations properly in this case?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Q&A from sister site unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/234539) discussing options for performing (math) calculations in `bash`

Answer (score 1):

If you ensure that you are running the script with bash (by for example adding a shebang)

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

Does that fix it?

Comment: I got error: "syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2*10000")"

Comment: I omitted the problem by "2*2/10" instead of "2*0.2", turns out that bash can't handle float numbers, weird.

Comment: @appendix while `2*2/10` will get rid of the error message, are you sure your variable does in fact contain the correct value?